# yii ajax form validation,require more fields base on certain field

Tags: ajax, validation, yii

I want to ajax validate my form,I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089333/yii-using-ajax-validation) which is working ok, but on value of the first column, I want to make user to fill other columns as well,

like if the value selected is a car, I want user to fill the licence plate number as well, but if user selected a bike, I don't need that licence plate number.

in before validate function in model I have implemented my logic, BUT the problem is in front end, if a field was not required before, but now is required, the form won't show this.

it won't get submitted but the form field will not get red, and the error message wont show.

how can I achieve this

Update:

I also put newly required field in models rules, and used `$('#my-form').trigger('reset');` to reset the form but those newly required fields wont
have red asterisk to show they are required.

also since I started a bounty, is there any way to show all messages for every field, before they have focus?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/466/a-simple-way-to-get-yii-client-side-form-validation-run-when-submitting-by-ajax/  Your requirement is custom one. It is good to write a custom script. Above link helps us to write such script to validate and do actions before submit

Comment: this one has bounty on it ... any one care to take 100 reps??

Comment: Your question seems interesting but it is hard to say something without seeing any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have an idea ... u have to create scenarios ... but there should be some fixed amount that u want to validate ... like as u said u have checkbox  car or bike (or radio or dropdown ) on selecting that you can load your form again via ajax where in that action you can set your scenario which will be for set for car if car is selected and for bike if bike is selected... and load form again with the selected option... with that particular scenario and you can validate that dynamically... i think this is the only way to do this ...

Comment: it's a good point of view, but I can't have fixed scenarios.I want to pass the required fields to the admin user.load the form again? like with `renderPartial`?

Comment: yes... like on selecting car .. load the form again with renderPartial and with use of setScenario and if else condition you can get to the scenario for car ... now u know car is selected so setScenario on the basis of seection... this is the way .. it is very tricky but will work... (and dont forgrt to use false and true at the end of renderPartial for yiiactiveform reload via ajax...)

Comment: your solution is the heaviest on data trafic, but in combination with loading the required fields from the database and loading the form will work, but I decided to have an ajax request and only get the required fields based on user definition, and just put asterics next to the fields label.

Comment: sorry bt for clientside validation u need to be form reloaded with the scenario of that model ... so may be you have to load full form again... only form... use $this->renderPartial('viewname',array('model'=>$model),false,true)

Answer (score 1):

The way I tackled this problem is by creating scenarios and dynamically updating them on the client side without loading the whole form again via AJAX.

In model.php create the scenario like following :-

```
...
public function rules(){
    return array(
        ...
        array('license_plate', 'required', 'on'=>'car'),
        array('some_column', 'some_validation', 'on'=>'bike')
        ...
    );
}
...
```

Now you asked if validations can be changed on user's choice of input. Supposing the user has to choose from a select(car or bike), car having the value 1 and bike having the value 2. Update your controller's create action like this :-

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new Vehicle();
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] == 'FORM_ID'){
        if($_POST['Vehicle']['type'] == 1)
            $model->setScenario('car');
        else
            $model->setScenario('bike');
        //You can have n-number of scenarios here based upon your application.
    }
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['Vehicle']))
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Vehicle'];
    if($model->type == 1)
        $model->setScenario('car');
    else
        $model->setScenario('bike');
    //You can have n-number of scenarios here based upon your application.
}
```

Now while doing this I faced a problem of error messages not going away even if the scenario was changed. I solved the problem using Javascript like this :-

(include this script in your view file)

```
$(document).on('change', '#DROPDOWN_ID', function(e){
    $(':input','#FORM_ID')
        .not('#DROPDOWN_ID')
        .val('')
        .removeAttr('checked')
        .removeAttr('selected');
    $('.help-block, .error').hide(); //NOTE 1.0
    var settings = $('#FORM_ID').data('settings');
    $.each(settings.attributes, function () {
        this.status = 2;
    });
    var form = $("#FORM_ID");
    form.data('settings', settings);
    $.fn.yiiactiveform.validate(form, function (data) {
        $.each(settings.attributes, function () {
            $.fn.yiiactiveform.updateInput(this, data, $("#FORM_ID"));
        });
    });
});
```

Please replace "FORM_ID" and "DROPDOWN_ID" with the ID of your form and the dropdown's ID on which the choices of validations depend in your form, respectively.

> Note 1.0 Explanation :
>
> I am using YiiBooster so all of my forms are in Bootstrap. Validation
>   errors in my form have class 'help-block error', please replace that
>   with the classes that are used in your form to display errors, to
>   correctly hide them.

References :

1. [Validating other fields on change of one field - Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630415/yii-ajax-form-validation-require-more-fields-base-on-certain-field)
2. [Changing scenarios on client side without loading the form again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600351/how-to-remove-the-client-validation-for-the-fields-if-the-check-box-is-uncheck)

I hope this resolves this issue.

Comment: your solution is good for static scenarios, but if I wanted to leave the validation of form, to the user(eg admin will say what other fields are also needed) this wont work, but thanks

Comment: btw you can reset the form more easily like this: `$('#FORM_ID').trigger('reset');`

Comment: IMHO I don't think Yii supports dynamic scenarios, I searched about it too :D
In your question you said you are implementing the check logic in your beforeValidate() function. Is it dynamic or static?

@tinybyte and to reset the form I applied that method because if I use your method it would also reset the dropdown used to select car or bike which would again change the validations of the form again. :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would need [custom validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) instead of the standard required rule.

Comment: validation is not the problem, showing in front-end is the problem,based on the first fields selection,other fields might be required, I want to be able to show that to client, client will get noticed that the form has some errors, but I need to show him to fill these newly required fields too.

Comment: Then, are you asked how to show/hide `<input>` elements based on the value of other fields? It is not very clear what you mean. Please show code & what you have tried.

Comment: I don't need to hide anything, just make them look like required fields.

Answer (score 0):

When the user selects bike/car from the dropdown for example you post the form to the controller, there you set a new scenario and you render partial the specific fields for the newly created inputs and insert them in the dom. Here comes another problem , they are not validated client side because they are not part of the currently rendered activeform. In order to achieve this take a look at my post here: 
[Dynamic added form fields based on 1-to-n relation - What framework alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695284/dynamic-added-form-fields-based-on-1-to-n-relation-what-framework-alternatives/22699275#22699275)

Comment: I could do what you purposed (like manually), but I wanted to know does [yii] support this, and also static scenarios wont work for me, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your logic will be implemented much easier with raw javascript than yii custom validation.
You could use an ajax dropdown which bind an ajax callback to that. By changing its value, your desired action will be invoked where domain logic will be validated there and a result (like true/false) will be returned which there you could decide which field you wanna show to the user.
You could also attach `required` class to the field you want after ajax callback.