# Dynamic added form fields based on 1-to-n relation - What framework alternatives?

Tags: codeigniter, symfony, yii, laravel, fuelphp

We have to develop a multi-model form that should use ajax calls to dynamically add or remove, sub-model fieldsets.

For example, let's imagine this team form **scenario**:

```
Team:
Team Name: 
Team Country:

Members:
Member A name: 
Member A age: 
      [add another member]

[REGISTER TEAM AND MEMBERS]
```

We are using **Yii** at the moment. As as far as we can tell **Yii doesn't support this out of the box (nor there is any extension that does this)**. Please don't tell me that there is, if you have not done it. As far as we can tell, **that's not possible at the moment** without A LOT of extending work.

So, we may try to integrate [Zend Form Collections](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically) but it seems a pain.

So, Zend do have this.

My question is quite simple:

From all developers and programmers here present, that use php frameworks, what framework do you use, in order to accomplish the scenario described above? Other than Zend, that, we know, do have this already.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would vote to close this as being "Off Topic". Clearly it's a programming question as they asking for alternatives to their current approach which isn't working for them.

Comment: I'm with Jakobud. This is NOT off topic. I'm not asking what is the best tool, or what is your fav tool. I'm asking a very specific programming question. For a given scenario, a given framework didn't accomplish the job. Does anyone was able to accomplish this specific kind of job with any other framework other then Zend? Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the final solution, form id is #quoteForm. Here you "merge" the settings of the two active forms:

```
//Add car button
        $("#addCar").on('click', function(){
            $.get('<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('quote/addCar'); ?>' + '?index=' + (carCount+1), function(data) {
                var settings = $("#quoteForm").data('settings');
                $("#quoteForm").data('settings', null);
                $("#carlist").append(data);
                var settings_new = $("#quoteForm").data('settings');
                carCount++;

                $.each(settings_new.attributes, function(k, v) {
                    settings.attributes.push(v);
                });
               //set the new settings
               $("#quoteForm").data('settings', settings);
        });
```

I actually use ActiveForm class which extends from CActiveForm and has this method which adds JS to the client script without running the widget(extracted form CActiveForm->run()):

```
public function registerJs()
{
    $options=$this->clientOptions;
    if(isset($this->clientOptions['validationUrl']) && is_array($this->clientOptions['validationUrl']))
        $options['validationUrl']=CHtml::normalizeUrl($this->clientOptions['validationUrl']);

    $options['attributes']=array_values($this->attributes);

    if($this->summaryID!==null)
        $options['summaryID']=$this->summaryID;

    if($this->focus!==null)
        $options['focus']=$this->focus;

    if(!empty(CHtml::$errorCss))
        $options['errorCss']=CHtml::$errorCss;

    $options=CJavaScript::encode($options);
    $cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
    $cs->registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform');
    $id=$this->id;
    $cs->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#'.$id,"jQuery('#$id').yiiactiveform($options);");
}
```

And here is the controller part. You create a form but only render fields, not using it as a widget:

```
 $form = new ActiveForm();
 $form->enableAjaxValidation = false;
 $form->enableClientValidation = true;
 $form->id = 'quoteForm';


 $car = new \QuotesHistory();
 $this->renderPartial('car_row', compact('car', 'carMakes', 'index', 'form'), false, true);
```

Here is a small part of the partial view($index is actually the carCount that is passed in the get request), also this partial has a lot more fields and they all validate and submit correctly:

```
<div class="field-box">
            <?php
                echo $form->hiddenField($car, "[$index]id");
                echo $form->label($car, "[$index]automake_id", array('class'=>'form-label'));

                echo $form->dropDownRow($car, "[$index]automake_id", CHtml::listData($carMakes, 'id', 'name'), array(
                    'data-target' => CHtml::activeId($car, "[$index]automodel_id"),
                    'empty'=>'Select Make',
                ));

                echo $form->error($car, "[$index]automake_id", array(
                    'class'=>'alert-msg',
                    'style'=>'margin: 0;'
                ));
        ?>
    </div>
```

And on the last partial you need to add this in the end of the view so that the JS is registered.:

```
<?php
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)  //we dont need this in normal render  
    $form->registerJs();
?>
```

One final step: In order all this to works you should not double include any JS libs in the ajax response. You can do this in jQuery - http://www.eirikhoem.net/blog/2011/08/29/yii-framework-preventing-duplicate-jscss-includes-for-ajax-requests/

I've tested this code now and it works. If I remove elements I have no problem submitting the form.

Comment: Nikola, believe me, we have tried all that and even more. Bottom line: Validations will not work. Try this: Add submodel fieldset. Validate. Remove submodel fieldset. Submit. You will notice what you are unable to submit. If someone could prove me wrong and show me a sample code, with submodels, ajax render partials and validation that works, I would be on heaven. As far as I can tell, the only way you have make this work, is if you pass a lot of jquery code as a (string), on CActiveForm attribute, including, the validation rules, but that defies the all purpose of using the framework.

Comment: What if your current number of members changes before the form is submitted? Also, client-side validation can be easily bypassed.

Comment: MEM I dont believe you because am currently working on a project with partial renders, client validation and submits that works. The code is written by me and I'm giving you extracts of that code. I'm using Yii 1.1.14, I have a render form with some data and I have a button that adds dynamically cars to the form, here's a bigger portion of the code. JS part.... it's too long for a comment, i'll post a new answer.

Comment: No dice Nikola. We are trying to see the error messages when the user focus out a given field. AjaxValidation doesn't seem to do that clientSideValidation seems to allow this, but it doesn't work. It places no class "error" on row element. Plus, the parent form doesn't work. If you have 5 minutes, perhaps we can chat and close this issue once and for all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well ajaxValidation doesnt do this but this way I trick the activeform to add the error elements, anyway I'm 100% sure I can resolve your issue with Yii and I'll help you do that. Please find me in skype phreak_bg.

Comment: MEM, you were right. The solution I proposed didnt completely solved the issue with the client validation, I checked our code and found out that it was done server side. So I've edited my answer and now it shows the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Nikola just added you to my skype. We may check issues there if you don't mind, and later, produce or just accept the answer. Thanks, really, for your time, hope to see you there and count on your help, because we are really clueless on how to truly and properly make this work.

Comment: @Nikola :( If you keep the ajaxValidation to FALSE, but try to make validadeOnSubmit = true (so that the validations for all submodels appear inline), it will NOT work. You will get a messy behaviour, not even logical. (because, if you repeat the steps, the behaviors seem to be different each time). NO JS is duplicated. We noticed that when we remove a fieldset, the correspondend JS doesn't get removed. No dice.

Comment: And even if we manually remove the script node for that fieldset, still, we can't get the form to submit (because Yii still things something is there).

Comment: @Nikola - I will make NO use of validateOnSubmit set to true in this case, and rely on server side if the user triggers the validation via submit button. It's not the ideal solution, but well... it works for now, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I would guess this could be done with any framework:

```
// Make an ajax (using jQuery or whatever you want to use) call using your new member info (and team id so the member knows what team they belong to
// (JavaScript)
var data = {
  'name' : 'John Doe',
  'age' : 7,
  'team_id' : 24
}
$.post(data, "/member/add", function(data)
{
   if ( data != true ) {
     // Parse error messages here and display them in your page.
   }
});


// member controller
// (PHP)
public function postAdd()
{
  $member = new Member(Input::all());

  $validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    $rules, // Validation rules defined wherever you want
  );

  // Validation fails
  if ( $validator->fails() ) {
      $messages = $validator->messages(); // I think this returns an array. Can't remember exactly. If not, conver it to an array of error messages
      return json_encode($messages);
  }

  // Validation passes
  $member->save();

  return true;
}
```

The above PHP is simple syntax I would use with Laravel, which makes stuff like this stupidly easy. I don't know much about Yii but I can't imagine why it wouldn't let you do such a simple operation. Laravel is really great and super simple to learn. I suggest it to any PHP developer these days.

Comment: The issue is exactly with validation integration and their appearance. Again, the point is to use and benefit from frameworks, Yii, can't pull something like this out. Wondering if other php frameworks can. We can do this using PHP. We know. We wish to find a way for accomplish this, using a existent framework, other then Zend. :)

Comment: The above example could easily have validation added to it using Laravel. In the controller method you would just validate the model, and if it fails then pass the errors back to the JavaScript as JSON, and then display the validation errors on the page. http://laravel.com/docs/validation

Comment: Thanks a lot Jakobud. That approach, is the one we are taking with Yii actually. But it doesn't work at a given stage. And the point is exactly that: The change of a framework is a major decision, and we must be sure that this can really be done, hence the request of any experience that one may have implementing those kind of forms using any php framework other then Zend, on a nice integrated way. Anyway, I may give a try on Laravel but, it would be less time consuming if someone just say: yes I've done it, using this framework - here's a rough sketch of the approach. :)

Comment: I added basic validation to the example. If the validation fails, just encode the error messages to json and return it, then parse those in your JavaScript and add them to your page however you want the error messages displayed. It's very easy. An even more simplified version would be to do your validation in your model when you save the model.

Comment: I wish to make those validation on the model, when I save. And that's what we tried to accomplish with Yii. No luck. Because you can add fields, remove fields, but if you ADD, then you validate, then you REMOVE then you try to submit, you will have those fields that were removed "somehow" triggering validation errors, even if they don't exist. The reason for this lies inside Yii guts. I will have a look on Laravel and let you know the results. Thanks a lot for your time and patience here. :)